# Trying to write a python function with a default sympy symbol

Tags: python, function, sympy

I am trying to write a function that has a sympy symbol with a default value, but am not getting what I expect.

Here is my code

```
import sympy as sy
def addtwo(y = sy.symbols('y', reals = True)):
    return y + 2

y = sy.symbols('y')
x = addtwo()
print(type(x))
print(x)
print(x.subs(y,1))
```

with output

```
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
y + 2
y + 2
```

However, the code

```
y = sy.symbols('y')
x = addtwo(y)
print(x)
print(x.subs(y,1))
```

gives the expected output

```
y + 2
3
```

Comment: In the first example, the `y` in `x.subs(y,1)` cannot possibly be the same `y` that's used inside `addtwo()`.  You must have had a left-over variable named `y` from some earlier code, as the expectation would be that this code would produce a NameError at that point.  There is no connection between two distinct Sympy symbols just because they have the same name.

Comment: You were right, and I modified my code so that it produces the output stated when I restart the kernel.  What can I do to get the desired output without specifying the input variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can consider returning the `y` symbols created in the function as well, i.e. `return y + 2, y`.

Comment: You can also consider making it dynamic. Only return the symbol if the user doesn't provide one.

Comment: Why not define `y` before the function `def` and its default keyword.  Sounds like the identity of that symbol is important and should not be left to chance or multiple creations.

Comment: If you make the default `y=sy.symbols('y')` it will work. (And spell `real` without the 's' when desiring to make a symbol have the Real attribute.) @David_sd has the "why" in his answer.

Comment: @hpaulj, in my actual example, not the MWE, there are times when I do not need the full output and so don't need the "y"

Comment: @jared, how do I make it "dynamic"?

Comment: @FredHickernell You can check if the user passed an argument for `y` and return the one created in the function if they didn't. If they passed one, then they should have the symbol and you can just return the addition result.

Comment: The relationship between python variables and sympy symbols (and their names) is the subject of at least one 'gotcha' section in sympy docs. There's a learning curve for both the base python, and the sympy layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these two symbols: `y1 = sy.symbols('y')` and `y2 = sy.symbols('y')`. Even though they are created at different times, they are equals: they have the same name and the same assumptions (none in this case, they are just complex symbols). Now consider `y3 = sy.symbols('y', real=True)`, which has the same name but different assumptions. So `y3` is different from `y1, y2`.

Going back to your first example, the substitution doesn't work because the symbol you created inside the function is different from the symbol you created outside. Said differently, the symbol you created outside is not contained in the expression.

Because you are dealing with an expression containing only one symbol, one possible solution is to retrieve it from the set of symbols contained in the symbolic expression, like this:

```py
import sympy as sy
def addtwo(y = sy.symbols('y', reals = True)):
    return y + 2

x = addtwo()
# .free_symbols returns a set of symbols contained in the symbolic expression
my_y = x.free_symbols.pop()
print(type(x))
print(x)
print(x.subs(my_y,1))
```

Comment: Thanks all for their comments.  Because I am a Python newbie, I  need a bit more help.

@Davide_sd, thanks for the suggestion, a bit cumbersome, but should work for my needs